# Possible to replace a FROM with DevSpace so dev uses a different reference without modifying the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devspace

I have a `Dockerfile` that looks something like the following:

```
# creating a node base
FROM node:16-slim as node-base
ENV CI=true

# builder-base is used to build dependencies
FROM node-base as builder-base
COPY ./package-lock.json ./package.json ./
RUN npm ci --production

# 'development' stage installs all dev deps and can be used to develop code.
FROM builder-base as development
WORKDIR /app
COPY . . 
RUN npm ci
EXPOSE 4001
CMD ["npm", "start"]

# 'unit-tests' stage 
FROM development AS unit-tests
RUN npm test -- --coverage --testNamePattern=UT: 

# 'integration-tests' stage 
FROM development AS integration-tests
RUN npm test -- --coverage --testNamePattern=IT:
```

In my Azure DevOps CI pipeline I'd like to "cache" the `development` stage by sending it to my Azure Container Registry (ACR). That way when I run `unit-tests` and `integration-tests` stages, I can just pull from ACR and hopefully save some time by not building `development` twice.

I can modify my `Dockerfile` to pull from ACR which would work for CI, but I'm pretty sure this would screw up running those stages locally. Locally, I wouldn't want to pull from ACR, and for it to be built locally since that has the most recent code the developer is working on.

Is there a way to do this with `devspace` without having multiple `Dockerfile`, modifying them, etc?

---

EDIT:
Actually, I might be able to accomplish what I'm after on the Azure DevOps side with `--cache-from` in the `build` command, and not have to modify the `Dockerfile` or `DevSpace.yaml` locally.

Idea came from here:
[How to Enable Docker layer caching in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266670/how-to-enable-docker-layer-caching-in-azure-devops)

Have to test it out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `appendDockerfileInstructions` option in combination with multi-stage builds (i.e. multiple `FROM` statements in the Dockerfile added in-memory via devspace): https://devspace.sh/cli/docs/configuration/images/append-dockerfile-instructions