# Azure Pipelines - Local Docker Build And Run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-pipelines

I have a container image A, then one B (extending A) and an azure Pipeline which is building them and running later in a docker compose.

I want all these without pushing the images to the azure repository (or registry), but by using the azure pipeline context (local build context, somehow).

I'm struggling in doing this, I'm getting this error when the pipeline is trying to build the B image:

```
Step 1/17 : FROM azure.repo.xxx/A:1.0.0
manifest for azure.repo.xxx/A:1.0.0 not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "1.0.0" is not found
```

Here are the pipeline tasks:

```
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build docker image A
        inputs:
          command: build
          containerRegistry: 'azure.acr'
          buildContext: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
          arguments: '--build-arg REPO_PATH=azure.repo.xxx --build-arg IMG_NAME=azure.repo.xxx/A:1.0.0'
          dockerfile: 'A/Dockerfile'
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build docker image B
        inputs:
          command: build
          containerRegistry: 'azure.acr'
          buildContext: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
          arguments: '--build-arg IMG_NAME=azure.repo.xxx/B:1.0.0'
          dockerfile: 'B/Dockerfile'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Enable Docker layer caching in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266670/how-to-enable-docker-layer-caching-in-azure-devops)