# Avoid Re-Downloading Container Images in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, containers

We run TestContainers tests, and this causes the download of large container images. Is there a way to cache and restore those, so they will be available faster in subsequent Azure Devops pipeline runs?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?view=azure-devops#can-i-reuse-layer-caching-during-builds-on-azure-pipelines) below:

[image]

It's currently not supported for Microsoft-hosted agent, you could use multiple-stage build and push to image registry as a `workaround`, or directly use `self-hosted` agent to cache the docker layers/images.

You can check similar [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59278682/14996050) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks, thats a bit too involved. I was hoping that maybe the "Cache" pipeline task could be used to restore them, similar to a Maven repository folder.

Comment: There is no task to cache the docker image currently. The nearest way you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061976/14996050) , or you can use self-hosted agent as mentioned above.

Comment: That only seems to work for images you build yourself, not for ones that you simply pull from an external registry, correct?

Comment: Yes, since there is no task to cache the docker image currently, we need to build the docker in pipeline. the trick is to use a pulled image as a base image or as a cache source when building a new Docker image(the option `--cache-from`), which speeds up the build process by reusing layers.